# How to write except no row found do something in sqlite Python

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

```
 def showPost(car_id, menu_id):

    car = session.query(Car).filter_by(id=car_id).one()
    slectedItem = session.query(CarType).filter_by(id=menu_id).one()
    creator = getUserInfo(car.user_id)

    try:
        getUser = login_session['username']
    except:
        pass
```

this code runs normal but I tried to test it with pycodestyle tool it returns that error:

Error: 
mine.py:460:5: E722 do not use bare 'except'

when catching the exception, mention specific exception when possible

What do I need?
        try:
         getUser = login_session['username']

```
    except ???:
            pass
```

I need if user Not Login so the getUser Function can't get the user name,
if  getUser return nothing pass

Comment: What don’t you understand from that error message? Can you explain what you’re trying to do a bit more? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should consider changing that try except block to an if/else statement

```
 def showPost(car_id, menu_id):    
        car = session.query(Car).filter_by(id=car_id).one()
        slectedItem = session.query(CarType).filter_by(id=menu_id).one()
        creator = getUserInfo(car.user_id)

        getUser = login_session['username']
        if getUser is None:
            pass
```

Also if this is for a web app you are building with flask you should consider using flask-sqlalchemy instead, it is a little easier to read and has some nice functionality like get_or_404 which will throw a 404 error if the item was not found in the database